# Tombstone object with Active directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, ldap

Is it possible to remove manually a tombstone object in win2008-r2 Active Directory ?

Comment: why do you want to remove tombstoned objects?  The only benefit I can thin of is reducing the AD size but the amount of space is normally negligible (unless you delete hundreds of thousands of records)

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a problem that you're experiencing specifically with AD 2008R2, I'm pretty sure that you can do it with NTDSUTIL or LDP

Comment: Yes, I could do this with ldifde.exe too, but each time I try I get :Add error on entry starting on line 1: Unwilling To Perform
The server side error is: 0x20ce The requested delete operation could not be performed.
The extended server error is:
000020CE: SvcErr: DSID-030902C5, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

Comment: Do all of these tools give the same sort of error?

Comment: The answer is incorrect. You cant manually delete tombstones. They will remain for the duration of the tombstone lifetime and will be cleared by the garbage collection process.